# Symmetrize Bones / Mirror Bones

Tags: rigging

I'm selecting necessary bones, go to the *Names > AutoName Left/Right*, and when I press *Symmetrize* it turns out like illustrated in the picture.

[image]
[image]

file: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you're expecting the symmetry to happen on the Y axis but the *Symmetrize* operation uses the X axis, so you need to rotate your armature 90° on the Z axis in *Edit* mode and symmetrize again. What we see is what is supposed to happen, your bones have been mirrored on the X axis.

Comment: @ moonboots does not work

Comment: @ moonboots ready

Comment: @ moonboots Im sorry,  how Add link into my post!?

Comment: @ moonboots I can't see the Edit Post button

Comment: @ moonboots  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=D483sAkr" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/D483sAkr/)

Comment: so, as I said, go in Edit mode, select all, rotate 90° on the Z axis, move the whole armature so that the origin is centered on its spine, then Armature > Symmetrize

Comment: @ moonboots Thank You very mach!